# Best way to convert IList or IEnumerable to Array

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a HQL query that can generate either an IList of results, or an IEnumerable of results.

However, I want it to return an array of the Entity that I'm selecting, what would be the best way of accomplishing that? I can either enumerate through it and build the array, or use CopyTo() a defined array.

Is there any better way? I went with the CopyTo-approach.

Comment: Does someone have a solution **without** Linq ?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Which version of .NET are you using?  If it's .NET 3.5, I'd just call `ToArray()` and be done with it.

If you only have a non-generic IEnumerable, do something like this:

```
IEnumerable query = ...;
MyEntityType[] array = query.Cast<MyEntityType>().ToArray();
```

If you don't know the type within that method but the method's callers do know it, make the method generic and try this:

```
public static void T[] PerformQuery<T>()
{
    IEnumerable query = ...;
    T[] array = query.Cast<T>().ToArray();
    return array;
}
```

Comment: It's 3.5 but the IQuery doesn't have a ToArray, nor does IEnumerable or IList either as far as I can tell?

Comment: Thanks man, that was useful. Would you say that there is any difference in calling Cast<>() from the IList vs the IEnumerable?

Comment: No - there's just the one extension method. (It's not within the interface itself.)

Comment: What if I don't know what MyEntityType will be when I create that array?

Comment: Then how are you going to use it afterwards anyway? If only your *caller* knows, then make it a generic type parameter in the method containing this code.

Comment: not sure i completely follow you. you mean something like var array = list.Cast<listType>().ToArray(); ?

Comment: I want to convert a non-generic IEnumerable to an Array, how should I do it? I prefer not using the cast, as there is no point in it.

Comment: @Shimmy: Yes there is... aside from anything else, it's telling the compiler what kind of array to expect! If you only want an `object[]` just use `Cast<object>`. The nongeneric `IEnumerable` doesn't have a `ToArray` extension method, so you can't just call `foo.ToArray<object>` or anything like that.

Comment: I am basically looking for the non-generic ToArray() method, it's already on my extension library using Cast, thanks Jon!

Comment: The `ToArray` extension method is in the `System.Linq` namespace, thought that might be good to know :).

Comment: @TomasJansson Thank you. I cleared unused usings and that's how I was missing that method.

Comment: BTW, if I return IEnumerable for various types (reflection call) - may i use `(MyEntityType[])query` instead of `query.Cast<MyEntityType>().ToArray()`?

Comment: @Alexander: Not unless the value being returned really *is* an appropriate array.

Answer (score 50):

Put the following in your .cs file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

You will then be able to use the following extension method from System.Linq.Enumerable:

```
public static TSource[] ToArray<TSource>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

I.e.

```
IEnumerable<object> query = ...;
object[] bob = query.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

I feel like reinventing the wheel...

```
public static T[] ConvertToArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");

    return enumerable as T[] ?? enumerable.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: can you explain your answer and also what you mean by you feel like you're reinventing the wheel?

Comment: heh - I actually kind of like this: in the off chance the enumerable is actually an array, you're skipping the new allocation/copy to steps in the `ToArray()` call (via the internal `Buffer` class)...although if anyone expected the "standard" copy behavior, they'd be quite surprised.

Comment: @Chris : 
Because I was inspired by the signature of ToArray () method in System.Linq.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx

Comment: For added ridiculousness the implementation of this method should call `IEnumerable.ToArray()`

Answer (score 6):

In case you don't have Linq, I solved it the following way:

```
    private T[] GetArray<T>(IList<T> iList) where T: new()
    {
        var result = new T[iList.Count];

        iList.CopyTo(result, 0);

        return result;
    }
```

Hope it helps