# IEnumerable to array of parameter

Tags: c#, linq

Using linq? and XML is there a way to convert this IEnumerable to a string array of the value parameter?

```
List<string> idList = new List<string>();
foreach (XElement idElement in word.Elements("id"))
{
    idList.Add(idElement.Value);
}
string[] ids = idList.ToArray();
```

It would be similar to
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268671/best-way-to-convert-ilist-or-ienumerable-to-array)

But I need the XElement.Value parameter

```
IEnumerable query = ...;
MyEntityType[] array = query.Cast<MyEntityType>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string[] ids = query.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: string[] ids = word.Elements("id").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray<string>();

Comment: Apress: Pro LINQ is a great book for learning some of these xml operations: http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590597897

Answer (score 2):

Use Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()