# Convert IList to array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, ilist, .net

I want to convert IList to array:
Please see my code:

```
IList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(1);
Array array = new Array[list.Count];
list.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

Why I get **System.InvalidCastException : At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type**? How that can be resolved assuming I can not use *ArrayList* as type for *list* variable ?

**Update 1:** I use .NET 1.1. So I can not use Generics, Linq and so on. I just want to receive result for the most common case - integer was given as example, I need this code works for all types so I use *Array* here (maybe I am wrong about using Array but I need, once again, common case).

Comment: ArrayList is obsolete. Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: Are you using .NET 2.0? If you aren't then this all becomes much simpler with the generic collections.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268671/best-way-to-convert-ilist-or-ienumerable-to-array

Comment: What version of .NET?  System.Linq adds a great function `ToArray()`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're creating an array *of `Array` values*. 1 is an `int`, not an `Array`. You should have:

```
IList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(1);
Array array = new int[list.Count];
list.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

or, ideally, don't use the non-generic types to start with... use List instead of `ArrayList`, `IList<T>` instead of `IList` etc.

EDIT: Note that the third line could easily be:

```
Array array = new object[list.Count];
```

instead.

Comment: Nice catch! I was thinking that he was using a constructor on the Array object.

Comment: @Jon What should I do if I do not know the type of elements in array? The integer was just example - I need more generic approach(without Generics)

Comment: @MichaelZ: You could use `object[]` instead.

Answer (score 24):

You can use Cast and ToArray:

```
Array array = list.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that

```
 Array array = new Array[list.Count];
```

even compiles but it does not do what you want it to. Use

```
 object[] array = new object[list.Count];
```

And, standard remark: if you can use C#3 or later, avoid ArrayList as much as possible. You'll probably be happier with a `List<int>`

Comment: It compiles because it's an array of arrays.

Answer (score 4):

probably the most compact solution is this:

`Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count).Select(i => list[i]).ToArray();`