# Convert boxed ienumerable into object array without knowing explicit type

Tags: c#

I've got a little code that pulls a boxed ienumerable instance out of an expression tree. The code needs to convert it into object[].

So far I've gotten away with assuming it'll be `IEnumerable<string>` and thus casting it followed with `.ToArray()`.

Circumstances have changed and now it could also possibly be a `IEnumerable<int>`. I still need to change the box into an `object[]` and don't really care what the type is.

---

```
object list = Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpression.Object).Compile().DynamicInvoke();

var enumerable = (IEnumerable<string>)list;
object[] values = enumerable.ToArray();
```

---

UPDATE:

Strings are references and Integers are value types. I've found that while I can box the reference to an array of ints, I cannot pretend it's an array of boxed ints as int's cannot be boxed.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code  Additional
>   information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.

```
object list = Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpression.Object).Compile().DynamicInvoke(); 
var enumerable = (IEnumerable<object>)list; 
object[] values = enumerable.ToArray();
```

Comment: Why not relying on `var list` and dealing with this variable without converting it into an array at all?

Comment: "int's cannot be boxed" not sure what you mean - they _can_ be boxed but just casting the collection does not do that _for you_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously answered in [Best way to convert IList or IEnumerable to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268671/best-way-to-convert-ilist-or-ienumerable-to-array).

Or you could do it the hard way:

```
  IEnumerable enumberable = (IEnumerable)list;

  List<object> values = new List<object>();

  foreach (object obj in enumerable)
  {
      values.Add(obj);
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for `IEnumerable<int>`, and definitely won't in C# less than 4.0. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant from C# 4.0 onwards, but AFAIK, variance doesn't work for value types. It'll work for `IEnumerable<string>` though (on C#>=4.0)

Comment: @Jcl I can confirm this doesn't work, I've tested and updated the question as appropriate

Answer (score 5):

Just call `Cast` before `ToArray`:

```
object[] values = enumerable.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Note that this casts each *item*, not the entire *collection*.  You can't "cast" a collection of `ints` to a collection of `objects`, you have to convert each item to an `object` (i.e. box them).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but you could theoretically cast it to `IEnumerable<object>` using Linq:

```
object [] values = ((IEnumerable)list).Cast<object>().ToArray();
```