# I tried to delete lines more than x characters but i'm getting error

Tags: c#

I tried to delete lines more than 35 characters but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

and I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

My code:

```
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("my path");
            lines = lines.Where(x => x.Length <= 35); // error is here
            File.Delete("my path");
            File.AppendAllLines("my path", lines);
```

Comment: Hover over `Where` in your code and inspect the return type. Notice that it's different than the type of `lines`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to convert IList or IEnumerable to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268671/best-way-to-convert-ilist-or-ienumerable-to-array)

Comment: before send your question search the currect problem , don't search and tell your story .

Answer (score 1):

When you read a file with `.ReadAllLines()`, you get an instance of String Array (`string[]`). When you use `.Where()` method, you get an `IEnumerable<string>` ... which cannot be assigned to a string array.

Simple solution would be to use `.ToArray()` to convert the result to a string array so you can assign it back to `lines` variable.

```
lines = lines.Where(x => x.Length <= 35).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of Jawad is on point. Note that there is another solution:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("my path");
IEnumerable<string> lines2 = lines.Where(x => x.Length <= 35); // error is here
File.Delete("my path");
File.AppendAllLines("my path", lines2);
```

(I'm using `string[]` and `IEnumerable<string>` to make clear the types returned by the methods). `File.AppendAllLines` accepts as a parameter a `IEnumerable<string>`, so you can pass to it the result of the `Where` without transforming it first to an array. Note that I had to introduce a new `lines2` variable.